# Multiply rows and search query

Tags: mongodb

I have to multiply rows with a number and then have to filter the data.

I have to multiply salary in field `SAL` by 12 for annual total and then find which one is greater than 30k.

I have already tried the multiply which is working, but after I get the data I can't filter, I tried to use match keyword also.

```
db.EMP.aggregate({$group:{_id:"$ENAME",Remuneration:{$sum:{$multiply:["$SAL","$COMM"]}}}})

db.EMP.aggregate([{$project:{total:{$multiply:["$SAL",12]}}} ,{$match:{"$total":{$gte:3000}}}] )


db.EMP.aggregate([{$project:{total:{$multiply:["$SAL",12]}}} ,{$gt:{"$total",30000}}] )
```

Data for MongoDB:

[image: Data for MongoDB]

Comment: Can you please provide the data in text rather than image? And in the MongoDB document format rather than table?

Comment: Also its not clear what your question is - can you please provide expected output?

Comment: @sheilak I have to make the Sal multiple by 12 which is annual salary then I have to find which people have an annual salary more than 30,00

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query using `$match` was very close, but you should use `total` instead of `$total` because as per [the $match docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/#restrictions):

> The $match query syntax is identical to the read operation query
>   syntax; i.e. $match does not accept raw aggregation expressions.

So your pipeline would be:

```
db.EMP.aggregate([
  { $project: { total : { $multiply : ["$SAL", 12 ] } } },
  { $match: { total : { $gt: 30000 } } }
])
```